bundle.js:21103 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hoverPoint') at S.onContainerClick (bundle.js:21103:17)
I'm developing a React application using Highcharts (Highstock) to display cryptocurrency data. In my Chart component, I have a Range Selector with buttons like "1m", "3m", and "All". When I click on these buttons to change the data range, I encounter the following error in the console:
bundle.js:21103 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hoverPoint') at S.onContainerClick (bundle.js:21103:17)
What I've Tried:
Removed direct calls to setExtremes in Range Selector button clicks.
Ensured the useResize hook is correctly implemented and imported.
Updated ChartProps to use CandleData[] instead of number[][].
Added the type field to each series in the Highcharts configuration.
Verified that data and volumeData are in the correct format.
Despite these changes, the error persists when clicking on the Range Selector buttons.
Here is my Chart.tsx component:
`
// src/components/Chart.tsx

import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts/highstock';
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';
import StockTools from 'highcharts/modules/stock-tools';
import AnnotationsAdvanced from 'highcharts/modules/annotations-advanced';
import DragPanes from 'highcharts/modules/drag-panes';
import PriceIndicator from 'highcharts/modules/price-indicator';
import FullScreen from 'highcharts/modules/full-screen';
import IndicatorsAll from 'highcharts/indicators/indicators-all';
import darkUnica from 'highcharts/themes/dark-unica';
import { getYAxisConfig } from '../utils/yAxisConfig';
import { getSeriesConfig } from '../utils/seriesConfig';
import { getStockToolsConfig } from '../utils/stockToolsConfig';
import useResize from '../hooks/useResize';
import './Chart.css';

StockTools(Highcharts);
AnnotationsAdvanced(Highcharts);
DragPanes(Highcharts);
PriceIndicator(Highcharts);
FullScreen(Highcharts);
IndicatorsAll(Highcharts);
darkUnica(Highcharts);

interface CandleData {
    time: number;
    open: number;
    high: number;
    low: number;
    close: number;
    volume?: number;
}

interface ChartProps {
    data: CandleData[];
    volumeData: any[];
    onRangeChange: (range: string) => void;
}

const Chart: React.FC<ChartProps> = ({ data, volumeData, onRangeChange }) => {
    const chartRef = useRef<HighchartsReact.RefObject>(null);
    const { ref, size } = useResize(); 

    const options: Highcharts.Options = {
        rangeSelector: {
            allButtonsEnabled: true,
            buttons: [
                {
                    type: 'minute',
                    count: 1,
                    text: '1m',
                    title: 'View 1 minute',
                    events: {
                        click: function () {
                            onRangeChange('1m'); 
                        },
                    },
                },
                {
                    type: 'minute',
                    count: 3,
                    text: '3m',
                    title: 'View 3 minutes',
                    events: {
                        click: function () {
                            onRangeChange('3m');
                        },
                    },
                },
                {
                    type: 'all',
                    text: 'All',
                    title: 'View all',
                    events: {
                        click: function () {
                            onRangeChange('all');
                        },
                    },
                },
            ],
            selected: 1,
        },
        title: { text: 'Crypto Historical Data' },
        stockTools: getStockToolsConfig(),
        yAxis: getYAxisConfig(),
        tooltip: { split: true },
        series: [
            {
                type: 'candlestick',
                name: 'Price',
                data: [],
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2,
                },
            },
            {
                type: 'column',
                name: 'Volume',
                data: [],
                yAxis: 1,
            },
        ],
        chart: {
            width: size.width,
            height: size.height,
        },
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        if (chartRef.current && chartRef.current.chart) {
            const chart = chartRef.current.chart;
            const priceSeries = chart.series[0];
            const volumeSeries = chart.series[1];

            const formattedPriceData = data.map(candle => [
                candle.time * 1000, 
                candle.open,
                candle.high,
                candle.low,
                candle.close,
            ]);
            const formattedVolumeData = volumeData.map(item => [
                item.time * 1000,
                item.volume,
            ]);

            priceSeries.setData(formattedPriceData, true, false, false);
            volumeSeries.setData(formattedVolumeData, true, false, false);
        }
    }, [data, volumeData]);

    return (
        <div className="chart-container">
            <link
                rel="stylesheet"
                type="text/css"
                href="https://code.highcharts.com/css/stocktools/gui.css"
            />
            <link
                rel="stylesheet"
                type="text/css"
                href="https://code.highcharts.com/css/annotations/popup.css"
            />

            <div ref={ref} style={{ width: '100%', height: '600px' }}>
                <HighchartsReact
                    ref={chartRef}
                    highcharts={Highcharts}
                    constructorType={'stockChart'}
                    options={options}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Chart;


My package.json
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.5.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^16.0.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.5.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.13",
    "@types/lodash.debounce": "^4.0.9",
    "@types/node": "^22.7.5",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.11",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "ajv": "^8.17.1",
    "ajv-keywords": "^5.1.0",
    "axios": "^1.7.7",
    "axios-retry": "^4.5.0",
    "cryptocurrency-icons": "^0.18.1",
    "date-fns": "^4.1.0",
    "highcharts": "^11.4.8",
    "highcharts-react-official": "^3.2.1",
    "klinecharts": "^9.8.10",
    "lightweight-charts": "^4.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
    "package.json": "^2.0.1",
    "rc-slider": "^11.1.7",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-select": "^5.8.1",
    "react-spinners": "^0.14.1",
    "react-tradingview-embed": "^3.0.6",
    "react-vis": "^1.12.1",
    "tulind": "^0.8.20",
    "typescript": "^5.6.3",
    "web-vitals": "^4.2.3"`

Question:
How can I resolve the Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hoverPoint') error when clicking Range Selector buttons in Highcharts React? Is there a better way to handle Range Selector button clicks to update chart data without causing this error?
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Could you please reproduce this problem in an online editor? You can start by editing this example: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/highcharts-react-demo-gnev1
